# Error in perl code - "Bizarre copy of ARRAY in leave at "

Tags: perl, debugging

I am having one problem in this perl code.
It is showing some error "Bizarre copy of ARRAY in leave at " . Although code is correct, I feel. Can anybody help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

sub getStatus() {
    #my $self = shift;

    my $status;
    my @details;
    my $Up = 2;
    my $Down = 3;

    $status = "Failed";
    push @details, $Up, $Down;

    my $detailMsg = join(",", @details);
    return [$status, $detailMsg];
}

my $info = &getStatus();
my $status = ${@$info}[0];
my $detailMsg = ${@$info}[1];
print $status;   
print $detailMsg;

exit 0;
-----------------------
Now debugging using perl -d option.
-----------------------
Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.28
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(test.pl:19):     my $info = &getStatus();
DB<1> n
main::(test.pl:20):     my $status = ${@$info}[0];
DB<1> n
main::(test.pl:20):     my $status = ${@$info}[0];
  DB<1> n
Bizarre copy of ARRAY in leave at test.pl line 20.
 at test.pl line 20
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
  DB<1>
```

Please suggest any solution. If this is related to problem in perl module, then how can we overcome. Please suggest.

Comment: The error you get outside the debugger should be something like `Can't use string ("2") as an ARRAY ref ...`.  `${@$info}[0]` tries to treat the length of the array `$info` is a reference to as an array reference.  You probably want `$info->[0]` there.

Answer (score 1):

`${@$info}[0]` is an abomination. `$info` is the return value of your `getStatus` sub. It is an array reference. Then, `@$info` is the dereferenced array. But, you are evaluating it in scalar context, so it evaluates to `2`. Then you try to evaluate that as an array reference, and take its first element.

Bizarre indeed. The error message is very appropriate.

PS: Don't use `&getStatus()`. `getStatus()` is the right way to invoke your sub.

PPPS: You probably do want `$info->[0]`, but then it is hard to be certain, because what you wrote is so bizarre.